# Does this sentence convey the idea and sound natural?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

I am translating a text, and I am struggling with this sentence. Does it sound natural and convey the idea?

'You can drive up to one meter close to the tables'

---> with the meaning that you can drive so close to the tables that there is one meter distance between the car and the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence does not sound natural. For one thing "drive up to one metre" means in the range 0 to 1 metres. I think you mean "drive up to the tables".

I would change it to

> You can drive as close as one metre from the tables.

Comment: Thank you so much! :-)